# Windows hibernation not working properly

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, memory, hibernate

When I turn the notebook on again after hibernation, it says that Windows found a problem and had to shut down.

I think the problem is with the transfer of archives from RAM to the disk, because it asks me to send MEMORY.DMP to Microsoft

The problem started after I configured dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and turned off windows hybrid-shutdown to access NTFS archives from Linux.
Also, the notebook didn't fall, so the HD is in perfect condition.

Notebook Dell Inspiron 14r, 3~4 months old.

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4VU5xyeq7mlQXlmM1I3S2lqZWM&authuser=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after [checking the dmp with Windbg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) I can see that the crash is caused by an old Realtek LAN driver from 2013 for your Ethernet chip (`PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136`)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe000295a0060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd0002c1ff960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0002fcb1d00, The blocked IRP

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
nt!PopIrpWatchdog
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KiIdleLoop



FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Rt630x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Rt630x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_rt630x64_image_pci.sys


!DevNode ffffe000295a0950 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&SUBSYS_05F31028&REV_08\4&30538de7&0&00E3"
  ServiceName is "RTL8168"
2: kd> lmvm Rt630x64
start             end                 module name
fffff801`76082000 fffff801`7614e000   Rt630x64 M (pdb symbols)          d:\sym\blue9600\Rt630x64.pdb\8421633104A247B5AFFCEF54DE1E8DD41\Rt630x64.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Rt630x64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\Rt630x64.sys
    Image name: Rt630x64.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Jul 26 09:01:35 2013
```

Get the [latest driver from realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) and look if this fixes it